# Export GA user accounts into a csv?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to export all the user accounts in my GA into a CSV file, Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) and [List All Users For An Account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUserPermissions#list). You should be able to use a CSV library to help convert it into something exportable depending on what language you're developing in.